# How to refer to line numbers of source code in listings without adding labels by hand?

Tags: listings, labels, code, line-numbering

I use `listings` to produce my Matlab code. There I can use the `\label` and `\ref` commands for readers to direct them to my code and line number.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Code for deflection at the point of intersection},label={lst:A.1},numbers=left,escapeinside={@}{@}]
@\label{lst:Li11}@In_x = X_num - 1;
\end{lstlisting}

As you can see in listing \ref{lst:A.1} line number \ref{lst:Li11}
```

My code is 700 lines and I have to discuss each line of my code by cross-referring. As you can see it's tiring. Is there any other way so that I can label the line number quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listings` doesn't add labels automatically to each line number, but we can use the `EveryPar` hook to do that. The following code defines a label for each line, based on the listing's `label` value plus the line number separated by a hyphen, so in your example `lst:A.1-1`, `lst:A.1-2` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{%
    \edef\@temp{\noexpand\label{\lst@label-\arabic{lstnumber}}}%
    \@temp
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    caption={Code for deflection at the point of intersection},
    label={lst:A.1},
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    escapeinside={@}{@}]
foo
bar
@\label{lst:Li11}@In_x = X_num - 1;
baz
\end{lstlisting}

As you can see in listing \ref{lst:A.1} line number \ref{lst:Li11} ...

As you can see in listing \ref{lst:A.1} line numbers \ref{lst:A.1-1}--\ref{lst:A.1-3} ...
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much.